# Should an "and" be placed before the last item in a list if the item is followed by an "etc."?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, lists, etc

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> - There are several types of email uses, such as professional, personal, and promotional etc.
> - There are several types of email uses, such as professional, personal, promotional etc.

I am not sure if there exists a difference between American and British English in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Etc* (‘etcetera’) means ‘and the rest’, so an *and* is already present, making one before *promotional* unncecessary.

As an additional thought, ask yourself if *etc* is really necessary. If it isn’t, then write ‘professional, personal and promotional’.

Comment: Thanks Barrie, I raised this query as MS Word processor sometimes brings up the suggestion of placing 'and', which created the confusion. Thanks for clarifying :)